# MySQL SELECT command usage for searching a string across multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have to make a search across two tables and display results from 3 tables.

Table: Clients ( tblclients )

- id
- firstname
- lastname

Table: Ticket Details ( tbltickets)

- id
- details
- clientid <-> The data is from tblclients.id

Table: Ticket Replies ( tblreplies)

- id
- ticketid <-> This data is from tbltickets.id
- details

Ok, What I want to do is to search for a string across the tables  ( tbltickets and tblreplies ) on the field *details* and I want to get the output of the result as the the follows

result must contains the following rows

- firstname
- lastname
- clientid
- id <-> From tbltickets.id

I tried multiple select queries. However, I am not getting the exact result that I wanted

Comment: Your best shot for getting help would be to post your SQL statement and get some help with it.

Comment: Show some code u tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, clientid, tbltickets.id as id 
from tblclients, tbltickets, tblreplies 
WHERE tblclients.id=tbltickets.clientid 
AND tbltickets.id=tblreplies.ticketid 
AND 
(
 tbltickets.details like '%SEARCH_STRING%'
 OR 
 tblreplies.details like '%SEARCH_STRING%'
);
```

Comment: That doesn't search for anything.

Comment: He is not talking about joining tables, he says he wants to search for some string whatever that is.